# Javascript: Overcoming standards mode differences

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I am having is with this code:

```
function scrollLeft() {
    document.body.scrollLeft -= scrollSpeed;
}
```

It works perfectly in Chrome and Safari but in IE and Firefox it is doing nothing. I have narrowed this down to the fact that in Firefox and IE standards mode they accept `document.documentElement.scrollLeft` instead of `document.body.scrollLeft`and my page is being rendered in standards mode.

Please note that I run this script at an interval of 10ms so I can't afford to have a large clunky detection script running each time this function needs to perform.

Does anyone know a cross browser way or an extremely light way of overcoming this? I am using the jQuery library in this script but Firefox and IE aren't recognising `$('body').scrollLeft()` either and I'm not sure why that is.

Comment: why not use [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scroll), [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scrollTo) or [scrollBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scrollBy) ?

Comment: @Esailija the problem is with selecting what to scroll, not `scrollLeft`

Comment: You are trying to scroll the window, yes? Those scroll the window. If you wanted to scroll a specific element, you would just use that element and not guess between <html> or <body>

Comment: @Esailija Sorry yes you are right, `window.scrollBy()` works perfectly. Perhaps make an answer and I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KISS: use [scrollBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scrollBy)

```
window.scrollBy( -scrollSpeed, 0 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the logical or operator to fall back.

```
document[body || documentElement].scrollLeft -= scrollSpeed
```

This is very quick, so very little overhead for you.

For bonus points do this instead

```
scrollLeft = (function () {
    var docEl = document[body || documentElement];
    return function () {
        docEl.scrollLeft -= scrollSpeed;
    };
})();
```

This only finds the relevant element reference once and closes over the temporary variable that holds it.

Comment: This causes an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined`

Comment: This won't work. `document.body` exists in all browsers so `docEl` will be equal `document.body` everywhere. You also have to wait until these elements exist in document tree.